# Table cell as top to bottom rather than left to right

Tags: html, css, html-table

Normally, we have table TDs aligned left to right.
I have a html page for desktop and mobile. For mobile , TDs arranged left to right are not visible so I want to show them top to bottom.
Is there any property that can arrange TDs top to bottom if width is not sufficient?

Comment: Reason #9719 tables are not to be used for layout.

Answer (score 1):

use `<tr>` instead of `<td>`

tr is a row, you can fill it with td's

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the  as rows.
So if you want to show all data in new line then use  for each 
For Example

```
<tr>
     <td>ABC</td>
<tr>
<tr>
     <td>PQR</td>
<tr>
<tr>
     <td>XYZ</td>
<tr>
```